# Why finally block is not given in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

All language like C#,VB.NET all have try catch finally block but SQL server only have try and catch only why not finally block is given is there any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 7):

There are many other problems with TRY...CATCH block, such as you cannot rethrow an error exactly as you caught it, so I would use C# error handling for anything complex. I have wrote a whole book chapter on it, you can download a free pdf [here](http://www.red-gate.com/specials/Ebooks/defensive_database_programming.htm?utm_source=simpletalkarticle&utm_medium=weblink&utm_content=DefensiveDatabase)

Comment: You mean you can't forward it as an object but are completely fine in capturing all data from the original exception into variables and using those to rethrow the exact same error, right?

Comment: @barthazar in sql 2008 there is no way you can rethrow exactly the same error.

Comment: I appreciate you can't rethrow `ERROR_LINE()` but everything else is there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the default error handling is often good enough.  It used to be hard to write code which could compile but cause some bad fault.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion TRY/CATCH/FINALLY is very much a procedural programming method and therefore does not really have a place or *need* to be included within T-SQL, what is considered to be very much a SET based programming language.

As *wallyk* states and I agree, the existing TRY/CATCH Block in T-SQL caters for the vast majority of requirements.

I wonder if perhaps you are trying to implement complex process logic that would be better housed/managed in the application tier.

Comment: I don't see how the set-oriented nature of the language makes it unsuitable for structured error-handling syntax. Before the TRY...CATCH syntax was introduced, passing and checking error codes was the recommended way to handle errors. This error-handling style is very common in C - a procedural language.